# Difference between Azure cmdlets - New-WAPackWebsite and New-AzureWebsite

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, powershell-cmdlet

What is the difference between Azure Cmdlets - `New-WAPackWebsite` and `New-AzureWebsite`?

Are they both aliases for the same to Create a new AzureWebsite?

In the same way I was able to see lot of other commands with `WAPackWebsite` (find below). Are they also the same aliases for `AzureWebsite cmdlets`?

> Disable-WAPackWebsiteApplicationDiagnostic
>   Enable-WAPackWebsiteApplicationDiagnositc
>   Get-WAPackWebsite
>   Get-WAPackWebsiteDeployment
>   Get-WAPackWebsiteLocation
>   Get-WAPackWebsiteLog
>   New-WAPackWebsite
>   Remove-WAPackWebsite
>   Restart-WAPackWebsite
>   Restore-WAPackWebsiteDeployment
>   Save-WAPackWebsiteLog
>   Set-WAPackWebsite
>   Show-WAPackWebsite
>   Start-WAPackWebsite
>   Stop-WAPackWebsite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WA prefixed commands are used on the Azure Pack which is an on-premise product which allows some of the services that run on Azure to be run on an on-premise datacenter/setup. You can ignore those as they are not relevant in your situation.

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer more? What is that on-premise product? In which situations we use this product? Can we use WA commands as aliases to regular commands?

Comment: As already mentioned on my original asnwer: The on-premise product is Azure Pack, it's used when you want to run some Azure services on-premise (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/windows-azure-pack/). 

I don't understand what you mean by "aliases to regular commands". WA  has different commands than the ones targeting the Cloud, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: What I mean by Alias - `I think New-WAPackWebsite will call internally New-AzureWebsite`, am I right? If you do `Get-Help New-WAPackWebsite`, in syntax you can see `New-AzureWebsite`.